# C - VS Code - Remove 'Expected Expression' Warning from Expression Statement

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, macros, vscode-debugger

I'm using a lot of macro that look like :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 #define max(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })

int main()
{
    int c = max(17,2); //error
    int a = ({int b = 9; b;}); //error
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

They use [expression statement](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) `({ *code* })`, and VS Code seem to hate it because each time I get a new error `Expected Expression` when I use this macro.
I can still run the code and it work fine using gcc, (because I guess it is not an error) but getting to many of them is annoying.

Is there is any argument with gcc to remove those kind of errors when compiling ?

(Ps: I use other more complex macro with expressions statements, so please don't suggest to make `max` a function).

More info about VS Code :

I get these errors during the compilation and from the code analysis.
I use the default gcc script to compile the program :
`task.json`:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe générer le fichier actif",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Tâche générée par le débogueur."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And If you are wondering what kind of more complex macro I use with expression statement :

```c
//Stand for Safe/Securised Memory ALLOCation
#define smalloc(size)\
({\
    size_t nbByte = (size_t)(size);\
    void* p = malloc((size_t)nbByte);\
    \
    if(p == NULL)\
    {\
        printf("smalloc of %zu bytes failed :\n", nbByte);\
        printf("line: %d, function: %s(), file: %s\n", __LINE__, __func__, __FILE__);)\
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
    }\
    p;\
})
```

Comment: Sounds more like a VS Code issue than a gcc issue.

Comment: VS C compiler does not support this extension (statement in expression).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do you get the warning/error during the compilation or from some code analysis of VSCode? If you get the warning from the compilation, copy&paste the compilation command and the warning message and tell us what compiler version you use. If you think your more complex macro cannot be replaced by a function, then please show this macro. Maybe someone can propose an alternative solution.

Comment: A you sure that VS Code does use your task.json. Looks like it use cl.exe.

Comment: this `smalloc` should expand to `smalloc_impl(size, __LINE__, __func__, __FILE__)` which should be a **function**

Comment: I'm sure VS Code use `task.json`, I changed the output directory to a bin directory and it work.

Comment: Try to inhibit all warning messages (-w).

Comment: You still did not show the compilation command that actually gets executed and the exact resulting error message. I agree with [tstanisl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989451/tstanisl)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69269141/c-vs-code-remove-expected-expression-warning-from-expression-statement#comment122432452_69269141).

Comment: I think you need to set the `intelliSenseMode` setting in the settings.json file, e.g. `"C_Cpp.default.intellisenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"`.

Comment: How do I get this settings.json file ?